# Rails Undefined Method Error for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So in my rails app, I have users with different permissions. When someone is logged in, everything works perfectly. However, when no one is logged in, I get the following error:

```
Undefined method 'editor?' for nil:NilClass

def require_editor
    redirect_to '/error' unless current_user.editor? || current_user.admin?
end
```

I think I understand exactly why this is happening: because no one is logged in, Rails is trying to figure out what role they have, and because there is no role for someone not logged it, Rails doesn't know if it should show the page or not.

My question is: How can I make a default role for someone who is not logged in, and send them to the error page that says they don't have permission?

Comment: Actually, `current_user` is just `nil` and `nil` doesn't respond to `editor?` or `admin?`. `nil` is Ruby's way to describe "nothing". But "someone not logged it" is not nothing. That [nothing is something](http://confreaks.tv/videos/railsconf2015-nothing-is-something) (excellent talk BTW). Using an object in place of missing one is known as the [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) and it's an elegant way to approach this problem. Where does `current_user` come from? Are you using devise?

Comment: @Stefan: hah, I knew "nothing is something" is something Sandi Metz would say. And, of course, it's her :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def require_editor
    redirect_to '/error' unless current_user && (current_user.editor? || current_user.admin?)
end
```

You're currently calling `editor?` on a `nil` object, which is throwing an error. By using the technique above, you're first checking to ensure `current_user` is not `nil`, and then perform the checks on `current_user` if it exists, if not it simply returns false and redirects to the `/error` URL.

Comment: This is called short-circuiting, it's an important programming concept:

When evaluating an **and**: it stops at the first `false`. Example: `false && raise "Error"` won't raise the error. When evaluating an **or** it stops after the first `true`.

Answer (score 5):

I usually do something like this:

```
class ApplicationController

  def current_user_or_guest
    current_user || Guest.new
  end

  class Guest
    def editor?
      false
    end

    def admin?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Then simply

```
def require_editor
  redirect_to '/error' unless current_user_or_guest.editor? || current_user_or_guest.admin?
end
```

This could be simplified by using [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) and extracting authorization logic from the controller. With cancan abilities set up, controller code usually looks like this:

```
def require_editor
  redirect_to '/error' unless can?(:edit, MyThing)
end
```

Comment: This! Extracting authorization logic is the best route to go. It's too easy to start with some conditionals only to become a bigger mess later.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `ApplicationController` create a method that redirects to the error page then add a `before_action` only on the actions that you wanna make sure the user is signed in

#### ApplicationController

```
def require_editor
  unless current_user && (current_user.editor? || current_user.admin?)
    redirect_to '/error' 
  end
end
```

#### Controller you wanna raise this error

```
class Controller < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_editor
  def new

  end
end
```

*If you are using `devise` gem there is a [callback/filter](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) for requiring authentications*